# How to rectify this error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT CU.CUST_CODE 
FROM AR_CUSTOMERS CU 
WHERE CU.CUST_CODE = TM.CUST_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_CODE
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TM.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_NAME
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE TM.INVOICE_NO = TD.INVOICE_NO AND ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY')MON FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')MM  FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
UNION
SELECT SUM(TD.QUANTITY)QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE)UNIT
FROM AR_TRANS_DETAIL TD
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
AND 
TM.JOB_DATE BETWEEN :STARTDATE AND :STOPDATE
GROUP BY 
CU.CUST_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_NAME,TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')
ORDER BY
MM ASC;
```

> ORA-00904: "TM"."CUST_CODE": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 22

Comment: You don't have access to TM.CUST_CODE there. Each SELECT is "isolated" from each other when doing UNION.

Comment: You're also getting different data from each branch of the union - different data types, and even different numbers of columns. Surely you meant to join those tables together, not union them?

Answer (score 2):

You're unioning together the individual select lists from multiple independent queries, which cannot see each other's data or results; and which are getting different numbers of columns and different data types. Several have no restrictions and will potentially get a lot of data you aren't expecting.

You should be joining the tables together, not unioning the separate queries; something like:

```
SELECT CU.CUST_CODE, ITS.ITEMS_CODE, ITS.ITEMS_NAME, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY') MON,
  TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY') MM, SUM(TD.QUANTITY) QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE) UNIT
FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
JOIN AR_CUSTOMERS CU 
ON CU.CUST_CODE = TM.CUST_CODE
JOIN AR_ITEMS ITS
ON ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TM.ITEM_CODE
JOIN AR_TRANS_DETAIL TD
ON TD.INVOICE_NO = TM.INVOICE_NO
AND TD.ITEM_CODE = ITS.ITEMS_CODE
WHERE TM.JOB_DATE BETWEEN :STARTDATE AND :STOPDATE
GROUP BY CU.CUST_CODE, ITS.ITEMS_CODE, ITS.ITEMS_NAME, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY'),
  TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')
ORDER BY MM ASC;
```

Untested and you need to check the join conditions have been converted as you expect.

You can read more about [the UNION set operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries004.htm) and [joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm) in the documentation.